# If statement on string wont work

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement

Hello so im working on an app for windows(C#) and android(Java) that the two communicate through TCP and i have got them both sending each other strings but when i want to see if the received string is equal to "abc", it wont work for some reason with the java side(I think). This is a bit of the java code for the android side

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] outputOutStream = new byte[1024];
bytesRead = ins.read(outputOutStream, 0, outputOutStream.length);

String received;
received= Integer.toString(bytesRead);

String str = new String(outputOutStream);

txtView1.setText(str);

String code = "abc";
if (str.equals(code)) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("You Said...");
    alertDialog.setMessage(str);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

But for some reason it wont have the `AlertDialog` pop up when I make the Windows(C#) send the string "abc" through.

Comment: Are you sure the Strings are indeed the same? Trying dumping the bytes. You may have an encoding issue.

Comment: What's in str? You should check.

Comment: When i have it display the string it does display "abc" but then when i check if it is equal to "abc" it says it isnt

Comment: Trye check str.kength, is it 3?

Comment: it is saying the length is 1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the byte content of the string using `Arrays.toString(str.getBytes())`.

I suspect the string will have lots of null bytes at the end because `outputOutStream` is not completely filled. The constructor you need is [String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29). Invoke it with 0 as the offset and `bytesRead` as the length.

Comment: Thanks you are correct, there are lots of null bytes at the end, so now im a bit confused on how i would use  String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) to fix this, Could you please give me an example?
(I'm assuming you are meaning `bytesRead = ins.read(outputOutStream, 0, bytesRead.length);` but im a bit confused)

Comment: `String str = new String(outputOutStream, 0, bytesRead);`